# Prove an identity of Lebesgue with geometry

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

I would like to prove this [identity](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LebesgueIdentity.html) :

> $$(a^2 + b^2 + c^2 + d^2)^2 = (a^2 + b^2 - c^2 - d^2)^2 + (2ac + 2bd)^2 + (2ad - 2bc)^2$$

Without developing each term but using some elements of geometry .

I explain :

The inequality is equivalent to :

> $$\frac{(a^2 + b^2 + c^2 + d^2)^2}{(2ab + 2cd)^2} = \frac{(a^2 + b^2 - c^2 - d^2)^2}{(2ab + 2cd)^2} + (\frac{2ac+2bd}{2ab+2cd})^2 + \frac{(2ad - 2bc)^2}{(2ab + 2cd)^2}$$

But now there is an interesting [fact](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclic_quadrilateral) :

For a cyclic quadrilateral with successive sides $a, b, c, d,$ semiperimeter s, and angle $A$ between sides $a$ and $b$, the trigonometric functions of $A$ are given by :

> $$cos(A)=\frac{(a^2 + b^2 - c^2 - d^2)^2}{(2ab + 2cd)^2}$$

So we have :

> $$\frac{(a^2 + b^2 + c^2 + d^2)^2}{(2ab + 2cd)^2} = cos(A)^2 +  (\frac{2ac+2bd}{2ab+2cd})^2+ \frac{(2ab - 2dc)^2}{(2ab + 2dc)^2}$$

Furthermore the second term in the RHS is just the second theorem of Ptolemy.

But I can't explain what is the the geometric meaning of the others terms like :

$$\frac{(a^2 + b^2 + c^2 + d^2)^2}{(2ab + 2dc)^2}$$

And

$$ \frac{(2ab - 2dc)^2}{(2ab + 2dc)^2} $$

In this context so can someone help me ?

Thanks

Comment: Using Carnot, I obtain 
$$ 
cos(A) = \frac{a^2+d^2-b^2-c^2}{2ad+2bc}
 $$

Comment: Ok, there are a lot of errors throughout the post. Starting from the Lebesgue identity

Comment: @Exodd Thanks for your interest normaly I correct all the faults .

Comment: Lebesgue's identity is equivalent to Lagrange's two-squares identity,
$$ (a^2+b^2)(c^2+d^2)=(ac+bd)^2+(ad-bc)^2\tag{1}$$
which on its turn is equivalent to the multiplicativity of the norm for the ring of Gaussian integers $\mathbb{Z}[i]$: $N(a-bi)N(c+di)=N(ac+bd+adi-bci)$. If we multiply both sides of $(1)$ by $4$ and recall that $2x\cdot 2y=(x+y)^2-(x-y)^2$, we immediately get
$$ (a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2)^2-(a^2+b^2-c^2-d^2)^2 = (2ac+2bd)^2+(2ad-2bc)^2.\tag{2}$$

Comment: @max8128  as Exodd mentioned, your cos(A) is wrong. i think there is an interesting idea but it wont work with the incorrect cos(A)